# Missing response header in UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers, shopify, urlfetch

I'm currently facing an issue while working with an API through Google AppScript.

I'm able to query the API and fetch the result, but I need to catch a specific header (link), that contains a key to use in a second query.

I'm using the getAllHeaders() method from [HTTPResponse Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getAllHeaders()), but obviously the targeted header is missing.

Do you have any ideas on how to get this header?

Here is my code :

```
function callShopify (action, productId, secondId) {

  var apiInfo = getShopifyFunction(action);
  var baseApiUrl = apiInfo[0];
  var functionUrl = apiInfo[1];
  var extension = apiInfo[2];

  var header = {'X-Shopify-Access-Token': getShopifyApiPass()};
  var options = {
    'method' : apiInfo[3],
    'headers' : header,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };

  var finalUrl = getShopifyWebsite() + baseApiUrl + productId + functionUrl + secondId + extension+"?limit=250";
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(1000); // lock 1 second
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalUrl, options);
  var test = response.getAllHeaders();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response.getAllHeaders())); 
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response.getHeaders()));
  lock.releaseLock();
  return (JSON.parse(response));
}
```

Here are the headers that are returned by AppScript method :

[image: headers that are returned by AppScript method]

As you can see the "link" header is not present.

To be sure the issue was coming from AppScript I also checked from Chrome Inspector : 
[image: headers returned by Chrome Inspector]

JSON Result for getAllHeaders & getHeader method :

```
{
   "Date":"Fri, 13 Mar 2020 18:36:47 GMT",
   "alt-svc":"h3-27=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-25=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-24=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-23=\":443\"; ma=86400",
   "Connection":"keep-alive",
   "x-sorting-hat-podid":"96",
   "X-Download-Options":"noopen",
   "x-shardid":"96",
   "x-sorting-hat-shopid":"10366451809",
   "Referrer-Policy":"origin-when-cross-origin",
   "x-shopify-api-version":"2020-01",
   "x-shopid":"10366451809",
   "X-XSS-Protection":"1; mode=block; report=/xss-report?source%5Baction%5D=index&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproducts&source%5Bsection%5D=admin_api&source%5Buuid%5D=86c9a9d7-96cd-4971-b1a6-57112df95a66",
   "X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff",
   "x-shopify-stage":"production",
   "Vary":"Accept-Encoding",
   "Content-Encoding":"gzip",
   "Content-Security-Policy":"default-src 'self' data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://* shopify-pos://*; block-all-mixed-content; child-src 'self' https://* shopify-pos://*; connect-src 'self' wss://* https://*; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src 'self' data: blob: https:; script-src https://cdn.shopify.com https://cdn.shopify.cn https://checkout.shopifycs.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://api.stripe.com https://mpsnare.iesnare.com https://appcenter.intuit.com https://www.paypal.com https://js.braintreegateway.com https://c.paypal.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://v.shopify.com https://widget.intercom.io https://js.intercomcdn.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri /csp-report?source%5Baction%5D=index&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproducts&source%5Bsection%5D=admin_api&source%5Buuid%5D=86c9a9d7-96cd-4971-b1a6-57112df95a66",
   "x-shopify-api-terms":"By accessing or using the Shopify API you agree to the Shopify API License and Terms of Use at https://www.shopify.com/legal/api-terms",
   "Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=7889238",
   "cf-cache-status":"DYNAMIC",
   "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies":"none",
   "expect-ct":"max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
   "x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit":"1/40",
   "x-stats-apipermissionid":"203626283105",
   "Report-To":[
      "{\"group\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https://monorail-edge.shopifycloud.com/v1/reports/nel/20190325/shopify\"}]}",
      "{\"group\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https://monorail-edge.shopifycloud.com/v1/reports/nel/20190325/shopify\"}]}"
   ],
   "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
   "x-stats-userid":"",
   "Transfer-Encoding":"chunked",
   "x-dc":"gcp-us-east1,gcp-us-central1,gcp-us-central1",
   "x-request-id":"86c9a9d7-96cd-4971-b1a6-57112df95a66",
   "Server":"cloudflare",
   "http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit":"1/40",
   "cf-ray":"5737dcc7198ff381-ATL",
   "Set-Cookie":"__cfduid=d9afe6e8299af1521516fd6a8cfa91f271584124606; expires=Sun, 12-Apr-20 18:36:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.myshopify.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax",
   "X-Frame-Options":"DENY",
   "x-stats-apiclientid":"3403993",
   "nel":[
      "{\"report_to\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"failure_fraction\":0.01,\"success_fraction\":0.0001}",
      "{\"report_to\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"failure_fraction\":0.01,\"success_fraction\":0.0001}"
   ]
}[
   20-03-13 19:   36:   47:   382 CET
]{
   "x-stats-apiclientid":"3403993",
   "nel":"{\"report_to\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"failure_fraction\":0.01,\"success_fraction\":0.0001}",
   "Date":"Fri, 13 Mar 2020 18:36:47 GMT",
   "alt-svc":"h3-27=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-25=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-24=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-23=\":443\"; ma=86400",
   "Connection":"keep-alive",
   "x-sorting-hat-podid":"96",
   "X-Download-Options":"noopen",
   "x-shardid":"96",
   "x-sorting-hat-shopid":"10366451809",
   "Referrer-Policy":"origin-when-cross-origin",
   "x-shopify-api-version":"2020-01",
   "x-shopid":"10366451809",
   "X-XSS-Protection":"1; mode=block; report=/xss-report?source%5Baction%5D=index&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproducts&source%5Bsection%5D=admin_api&source%5Buuid%5D=86c9a9d7-96cd-4971-b1a6-57112df95a66",
   "X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff",
   "x-shopify-stage":"production",
   "Vary":"Accept-Encoding",
   "Content-Encoding":"gzip",
   "Content-Security-Policy":"default-src 'self' data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://* shopify-pos://*; block-all-mixed-content; child-src 'self' https://* shopify-pos://*; connect-src 'self' wss://* https://*; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src 'self' data: blob: https:; script-src https://cdn.shopify.com https://cdn.shopify.cn https://checkout.shopifycs.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://api.stripe.com https://mpsnare.iesnare.com https://appcenter.intuit.com https://www.paypal.com https://js.braintreegateway.com https://c.paypal.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://v.shopify.com https://widget.intercom.io https://js.intercomcdn.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri /csp-report?source%5Baction%5D=index&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproducts&source%5Bsection%5D=admin_api&source%5Buuid%5D=86c9a9d7-96cd-4971-b1a6-57112df95a66",
   "x-shopify-api-terms":"By accessing or using the Shopify API you agree to the Shopify API License and Terms of Use at https://www.shopify.com/legal/api-terms",
   "Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=7889238",
   "cf-cache-status":"DYNAMIC",
   "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies":"none",
   "expect-ct":"max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
   "x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit":"1/40",
   "x-stats-apipermissionid":"203626283105",
   "Report-To":"{\"group\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https://monorail-edge.shopifycloud.com/v1/reports/nel/20190325/shopify\"}]}",
   "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
   "x-stats-userid":"",
   "Transfer-Encoding":"chunked",
   "x-dc":"gcp-us-east1,gcp-us-central1,gcp-us-central1",
   "x-request-id":"86c9a9d7-96cd-4971-b1a6-57112df95a66",
   "Server":"cloudflare",
   "http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit":"1/40",
   "cf-ray":"5737dcc7198ff381-ATL",
   "Set-Cookie":"__cfduid=d9afe6e8299af1521516fd6a8cfa91f271584124606; expires=Sun, 12-Apr-20 18:36:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.myshopify.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax",
   "X-Frame-Options":"DENY"
}
```

Comment: I don't see some of the other ones in `test` either. Like `nel`. What happens if you try `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response.getAllHeaders())); Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response.getHeaders()));`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just edited my post to add the JSON response.

Comment: Can you look at the full payload your browser is sending and make sure you’re sending the same?

Comment: SO i checked, the only difference i can see is, from my browser i'm using HTTP Basic Authentication as preconised by the CMS . For example : https://login:password@mywebsite/admin/api/2020-01/products.json?limit=250               when i'm gonna use an an header with a token authentication from the script.

Comment: Check the destination API documentation. Does it require auth? You might need to pass auth token in your fetch call.

Comment: let's save time, i've edited my post to show the full call

Comment: Have you tried making this call in an API tester? I use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/talend-api-tester-free-ed/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm. Try to see if you can re-create the API call outside of GAS. Once you get it working there, duplicate in GAS with the same headers.

Comment: Thanks i'll try right away and get back in touch here

Answer (score 3):

First of all many thanks to [IMTheNachoMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3383907/imthenachoman).

I've been able to figure out this issue just by updating the call method. Obviously the API does not return the same headers when using HTTP basic authentication VS token based authentication. By switching to HTTP Basic Auth, i'm able to retrieve the targeted header.

Just for informations, here is the code i now use :

```
  var USERNAME = "myusername";
  var PASSWORD = "mypassword";

    var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };

  var params = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":headers
  };

  var finalUrl = 'https://mywebsite/admin/api/2020-01/products.json?limit=250'
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalUrl, params);
  var test = response.GetAllHeaders();
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
```

Comment: Thanks for that this is an area I'm really weak in and I appreciate you posting your working solution.

Comment: You should ask the API provider why this is. I feel like a token based authentication is more secure than basic so it would be preferred/ideal to use that.

Comment: Thank you ! After consultation, it was a temporary bug in from the API side, 24h later the bug has been corrected, and i've been able to re use the token based authentication.